# Where is .Values taken from in kubernetes configuration yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I can't seem to find the formal definition of `.Values` (taken from [here](https://github.com/instana/robot-shop/blob/master/K8s/helm/templates/mysql-deployment.yaml#L22))

```
image: {{ .Values.image.repo }}/rs-mysql-db:{{ .Values.image.version }}
```

From the docs, it is definitely related to [helm chart](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/values/):

> Note that all of Helm's built-in variables begin with an uppercase letter to easily distinguish them from user-defined values: .Release.Name, .Capabilities.KubeVersion.

But in the above example ([robot-shop/K8s/helm/templates](https://github.com/instana/robot-shop/tree/master/K8s/helm/templates)) I don't see any `values.yaml` file - what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's under the `helm` folder:

https://github.com/instana/robot-shop/blob/master/K8s/helm/values.yaml

```
# Registry and repository for Docker images
# Default is docker/robotshop/image:latest
image:
 repo: robotshop
 version: latest
 pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Comment: ohhhh ... what is the rule though? does it have to be named `values.yaml`? can it reside in any arbitrary folder above? can there be *more* than one `values.yaml` file?

Comment: The values file will be in the main chart folder, beside the "templates" folder. and yes, could be more than 1 file (values.dev.yaml for example).

Comment: The Helm documentation introductory material on [Customizing the Chart Before Installing](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#customizing-the-chart-before-installing) discusses the places values can come from, in addition to the chart's `values.yaml` file.

Comment: @DavidMaze, if I understood correctly, when multiple `values.yaml` files exist I *can not* know which one of them is going to be used, right?

Comment: You can, you specify the values file name/location when you perform helm install/upgrade.

Comment: They're all merged together, left-to-right in command-line order, with the chart's `values.yaml` having lowest precedence.